# What domain to set in rDNS

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, reverse-dns

I have a few different domains on a shared IP address. One of them is having trouble sending email, as certain mail servers reject the email for not having rDNS set up properly.

The thing is there are several domains using that IP address. If I set the rDNS up for one domain, will if effect the other domains since when those domains try to send email the rDNS lookup will not match their domain?

Right now I have my main hosting site, my client sites, and the mail server are running on the same machine. My main site uses a different IP from all the client sites though, and the clients all share an IP.

If I set the rDNS lookup of the IP address shared with the clients to point to my main hosting site, would that help at all? In that case a rDNS lookup for myClientsSite.com would return MySite.com.

Don't fully understand rDNS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I set the rDNS up for one domain, will if effect the other domains
>   since when those domains try to send email the rDNS lookup will not
>   match their domain?

RDNS should be the HOST name, not the domain. ANd it has to be the one the host pretends to be when you connect via SMTP - the rest is irrelevant. The server says it is X, and the reverse of the IP must map to X.